# How can I get the current user's group in forms.py in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a scenario where i need to pass the logged-in user's groud name and get the list users in that group.

forms.py -- in the below code i need to pass the user's group instead of **Banglore**

```
class UpateTaskMaster(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UpateTaskMaster, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    users = User.objects.filter(groups__name='Banglore')
    self.fields['processor'].choices = [(user.pk, user.get_full_name()) for user in users]
class Meta():
    model  = TaskMaster
    fields = ["sid","tasktype","task_title","task_description","datacenter","status","priority","sourceincident","processingteam","duedate","pid","errorincident",'processor']
    widgets = {
               'sid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mr-sm-2'}),
               'task_title':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'materialize-textarea'}),
               'task_description':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'materialize-textarea'}),
               'sourceincident': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mr-sm-2'}),
               'pid': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mr-sm-2'}),
               'errorincident': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mr-sm-2'}),
               'duedate' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using :

```
user_groups = request.user.groups.all()
```

Then, you can iterate it as you need